# How many conditions can be included in 'while' loop and how?

Tags: c++, while-loop, range, do-loops

I want to apply more than one while loop so it can do the calculations below but within the given range. eg. `p_fifties-= fifties` must calc while it is between `0 < x < 10`. So when it's more than 10 it must do the next calculation.

I was wondering if I can add more than one while loop at the end so it gives a range for each calculation. Is it possible?

```
  do{
  p_fifties  -= fifties; 
  p_twenties -= twenties;
  p_tens -= tens;
  } while();
```

Comment: what do you mean? give full example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You question is a bit unclear,

but do you mean =>

All counters reach 0:

```
do{
  p_fifties  -= fifties; 
  p_twenties -= twenties;
  p_tens -= tens;
  } while
(p_fifties > 0 &&  
  p_twenties > 0 &&
  p_tens > 0)
```

Any one counter reaches 0:

```
do{
  p_fifties  -= fifties; 
  p_twenties -= twenties;
  p_tens -= tens;
  } while
(p_fifties > 0 ||  
  p_twenties > 0 ||
  p_tens > 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

The question is a bit unclear. The language accepts only a single condition in the `while( ... )`, but a condition can be built by combining several sub-conditions with logical operators. Example:

```
do {
  p_fifties  -= fifties; 
  p_twenties -= twenties;
  p_tens -= tens;
} while( p_fifties >= 20 && ( p_twenties >= 5 || p_tens > 0 ) );
```

where `&&` is a logical *and* and `||` is a logical *or*.

Answer (score 1):

You can use &&

```
 do
 {
     p_fifties  -= fifties; 
     p_twenties -= twenties;
     p_tens -= tens;
  } while(p_fifties>0 && p_twenties>0 &&  p_tens>0);
```

Answer (score 0):

As many as you want using logic operators

If there are too many conditions consider using a function call in the while loop condition.